# beginner: problem with time and text facet

Tags: openrefine

1 I have a column called "time" and in its cells i have the 00:00:00 format however in refine it becomes [Sun Dec 31 00:00:00 CET 1899](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VFlxj.png), how can i fix that?

2 I have another column called "year" with three types of cells: 2020, 2019 and 2018... however when I select text face I [see them as 2020.0, 2019.0 and 2018.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DeQYS.png)  and what is problematic is that when I include 2018.0 for instance it [creates a duplicate of 2018.0 with zero row selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XExWL.png) basically making impossible to group results. first time that is happens, any idea?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

This is a [known bug](https://github.com/OpenRefine/OpenRefine/issues/1908) that only occurs when importing Excel files (the problem does not occur if you first export your Excel file in csv).

Until the problem is fixed, here is a workaround.

In your column containing the times, click on "Edit cells" then "Transform" and apply the following GREL formula:

```
value.find(/\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}/)[0]
```

Same thing in the column containing the years, but with this formula:

```
value.toString().replace(".0", "").toNumber()
```

Comment: amazing, thank you, actually the time formula somehow removes the bug for the year one as well without using the second formula